# curl to python requests conversion for solr query

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, solr

I have a bit of a bizzare problem. I have a solr index, which I query using curl like so:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select?indent=on&q="galvin%20life%20sciences"~0&wt=json&sort=_docid_%20desc&rows=5'
```

and I get (note the `q` string and the tilde operator which I use for proximity search):

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"\"galvin life sciences\"~0",
      "indent":"on",
      "sort":"_docid_ desc",
      "rows":"5",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":61,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
```

Now, I am trying to replicate the same thing in python using:

```
resp=requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select?q=' + "galvin%20life%20sciences"+"~0" + '&wt=json&rows=5&start=0&fl=id,org*,score')
```

and I get this:

```
[
    {
        "responseHeader": {
            "status": 0,
            "QTime": 0,
            "params": {
                "q": "galvin life sciences~0",
                "fl": "id,org*,score",
                "start": "0",
                "rows": "5",
                "wt": "json"
            }
        },
        "response": {
            "numFound": 3505398,
            "start": 0,
            "maxScore": 9.792607,
            "numFoundExact": true,
            "docs": [
```

YOu can see that the queries are somehow different:

```
curl: "q":"\"galvin life sciences\"~0",
requests: "q": "galvin life sciences~0",
```

so I am getting wrong results when using requests.

I am not sure what I should do in requests to make the queries match.

I have tried the solution of @Mats:

```
requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select', params={
  'q': '"galvin life sciences"~0',
  'wt': 'json',
  'rows': 5,
  'start': 0,
  'fl': 'id,org*,score',
})
```

but now I am not able to pass the variable to it (how annoying). So I have:

```
q_solr="Galvin life sciences"
requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select', params={
  'q': q_solr+'~0',
  'wt': 'json',
  'rows': 5,
  'start': 0,
  'fl': 'id,org*,score',
})
```

but this gives me no result.. WTAF!!!!

Comment: Hi AJW, Did you try once with postman or any other API testing tool?
If you did then please share those screenshots as well

Comment: no its the wrong tool for the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `requests` built-in support for creating URL parameters for you (which is what I'd recommend, as it lets you properly separate the parameters and requests handles escaping for you):

```py
requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select', params={
  'q': '"galvin life sciences"~0',
  'wt': 'json',
  'rows': 5,
  'start': 0,
  'fl': 'id,org*,score',
})
```

Otherwise you can build the URL yourself as you've done, but since you've concatenated the strings instead of having `"` inside the previous string, you've just merged `q=` with `galvin ..`  instead of `"galvin`. There's no need to end the previous string if the next one is included anyways. You can also use a backslash to escape any quotes inside a string if necessary.

```py
resp=requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select?q="galvin%20life%20sciences"~0&wt=json&rows=5&start=0&fl=id,org*,score')
```

But use the first form unless you're getting a preformatted URL from a different source.

Comment: omg I did not know I could do that. Can I ask what if I have a variable I want to pass inside the param? how do I pass it? so, `q_solr=galvin life sciences` how do I pass it to `q` within param please?

Comment: In that case you should really apply Solr escaping to the values as well - if they're controlled by untrusted users you need to avoid a user being able to manipulate the query to get Solr to what you want. In that case, use a proper client like pysolr: https://pypi.org/project/pysolr/ instead of using `requests` directly. If you can trust the values, you can either concatenate the string: `'q': '"' + q_solr + '"',` or use a f-string (py3.6+): `'q': f'"{q_solr}"',` or use a format string (< py3.6): `'q': '"%s"'.format(q_solr),`

Comment: ah thank you!!! the `f-string` worked.. what a nightmare. thank you ever so much.. you saved my day :) thank you also for sharing your knowledge.